# How do I use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, crud

**State Problem**

Apart from 1st col in MySQL server which is PK and auto_increment, col "**C**" is STRING/VARCHAR. How do I use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on col "**C**".

*Should I also set col "**C**" as UNIQUE as well?*

**Example**

Assume that my table in MySQL server looks similar to this...

```
---------------------------
|ID(PK)| A | B | C | D | E |
+------+---+---+---+---+---+
|   1  |   |   |   |   |   |
|   2  |   |   |   |   |   |
|   3  |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------
```

**What I expect**

The duplicate input must be ignored from the MySQL server.

*Can I also send alert pop-up/session pop-up, if the duplicate has been inserted into MySQL server as **"This query has already existed."**?*

Comment: Of course you would need a key on the `C` column, this is named ON DUPLICATE **KEY** for a reason.

Comment: @04FS So, I should set col  `C` as UNIQUE in MySQL server and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only on col `C` ?

Comment: 'If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html best if you review the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Column C must be set to NOT NULL, UNIQUE then SQL will return error against attempt of duplicate value insert. You may handle that error in your backend code. Or you can handle and alter the duplicate value with 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' clause:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```